# Locate specific file from script

Tags: bash, centos, scripting, path

I've written a script file in which, one function searches for another script and if found, executes that script.

**Script extract**

```
#!/bin/bash
...
service_status() {
local my_script=`which my-services-check.sh 2>/dev/null`
[[ -z "$my_script" ]] && { echo -n "functionality not available" ; failure ; echo ; return ; }
source $my_script    
}
...
```

When I do `which my-services-check.sh 2>/dev/null` from the terminal, it returns the correct path to that file.

When I run that function **service_status()** (when calling the script), it doesn't find the file (`$my_script` is empty).

Instead of using `which` I've tried with `type` and `command` but I end up with the same result.

**Path issue**

Then I printed out `$PATH` from the terminal and from the script, and sure enough they aren't the same!
When executed from my script, the `$PATH` is set to be the secure PATH, as defined in `/etc/sudoers`:

`Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

*From the terminal*

`echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin: ...`

So,

1. how can I reliably find the file I'm looking for, from my script? (without using `find` as the file I need must be in the PATH)?
2. and how come the PATH is set differently when executed from a script?

Comment: @slm, any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

The interactive shell loads `.bashrc`, the script doesn't. If your `$PATH` is set in `.bashrc` *and you don't export it*, the script doesn't inherit your modifications to `$PATH`. If you call `export PATH`, the script should see it. Check `export -p` to see what variables get exported (`$PATH` should be among them). Also check `$BASH_ENV` which could potentially override your `$PATH`.

Ideally, the `$PATH` should be set and exported in your `.profile`, so that it gets loaded and set when you login, and is visible to everything you run from then on forward.

It's a good practice to check not only if the filename exists, but if it is a proper file, `[[ -f "$my_script" ]]` or (in case you wanted to call it as a script instead of sourcing it), the switch `-x`.

Comment: "If your $PATH is set in .bashrc and you don't export it, the script doesn't inherit your modifications to $PATH." That is wrong. For the simple reason that `PATH` is (under normal conditions) in every process's environment. Writing to an existing environment variable does modify it for all child processes. You don't have to export it as it is already exported. The problem is that `PATH` is overwritten during script shell initialization.

Comment: Well that's why I'm saying to check if it is exported - it should be, but you never know. A noninteractive shell shouldn't have any additional initialization that would override the `$PATH`. Unless `$BASH_ENV` is set to something. That's also something to check.

Comment: @orion, `export -p` report the PATH being exported with all relevant paths as when run from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any such thing as a guaranteed set of directories to include in `PATH`. You'll find `/bin` but everything else is just probable or possible. Users on my systems will have something like `$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`. Root users would have `/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin` in there too.

If your file might be in one of a number of places you could search for it in those possible places. Just remove the entire dependency on `PATH` out of this search, or extend PATH to include the minimum set of places your script might be found.

```
local OPATH="$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:/extra/place:/another/extra/place"
local my_script=$( which my-services-check.sh 2>/dev/null )
PATH="$OPATH" # Restore the original PATH (optional)

if test -z "$my_script"; then ...; fi
. "$my_script"
```

Alternatively just set `PATH` to the required value at the top of the script. There's no reason, once your initial script is running, why you can't set `PATH`. I tend to do this in many of my scripts simply so I know the environment is plausible.